# Jaydata webapi Offline Sync

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, asp.net-web-api, jaydata

I am analyzing Jaydata with Web API and online offline sync for phonegap applicaon

**Controller**

```
  public TodoItem[] Get()
        {
                    return _db.TodoItems.ToArray();
        }
```

**Jaydata Context**

```
    (function (global, $data, undefined) {


        $data.Entity.extend('TodoItem', {
            'Id': { type: Number },
            'Task': { type: String },
            'Completed': { type: Boolean },
        });
        $data.EntityContext.extend('db', {
                TodoItems: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: TodoItem }

        });

})(window, $data);
```

**local DB creation in Jaydata**

```
var localDB = new db({ name: 'local', databaseName: 'db' });
```

**Call to api controller**

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON("/api/values/", function (data) {
        syncSet(data, localDB.TodoItems);
    });

});
```

This jquery works fine for fist time when I am adding items to local store, now I want check and update if any thing changed or add new items if any new items form server

How can I write generic jquery function for the sync

```
function syncSet(fromSet, toSet) {
    $.each(fromSet, function (key, value) {
        localDB.TodoItems.add(value);
    });
    localDB.saveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two recommended articles to achieve your sync goal:

- [How to create a synchronized Online/Offline data application with
  EntityFramework, JavaScript and JayData](http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-create-a-synchronized-online-offline-data-application-with-javascript-and-jaydata)
- [Synchronizing changed entities in online-offline scenarios](http://jaydata.org/blog/synchronizing-changed-entities-in-online-offline-scenarios)